# Is there a way to minimise CPU usage by reducing number of write operations to chrome.storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that keeps track of the time I spend on each site.
In the `background.js` I am using a map(stored as an array) that saves the list of sites as shown.

```
let observedTabs = [['chrome://extensions', [time, time, 'icons/sad.png']]];
```

Every time I update my current site, the starting and ending time of my time on that particular site is stored in the map corresponding to the site's key.
To achieve this, I am performing the `chrome.storage.sync.get` and `chrome.storage.sync.set` inside the `tabs.onActivated`, `tabs.onUpdated`, `windows.onFocusChanged` and `idle.onStateChanged`.
This however results in a very high CPU usage for chrome(around 25%) due to multiple read and write processes from(and to) storage.

I tried to solve the problem by using global variables in `background.js` and initialising them to `undefined`. Using the function shown below, I read from storage only when the the current variable is undefined(first time `background.js` tries to get the data) and at all other times, it just uses the set global variable.

```
let observedTabs = undefined;
function getObservedTabs(callback) {
   if (observedTabs === undefined) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get("observedTabs", (observedTabs_obj) => {
        callback(observedTabs_obj.observedTabs);
    });
    } else {
          callback(observedTabs);
    }   
}
```

This solves the problem of the costly repeated read operations.
As for the write operations, I considered using `runtime.onSuspend` to write to storage once my background script stops executing, as shown:

```
chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(() => {
    getObservedTabs((_observedTabs) => {
        observedTabs = _observedTabs;
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"observedTabs": _observedTabs});
    });
});
```

This, however doesn't work. And the documentation also warns about this.

> Note that since the page is unloading, any asynchronous operations started while handling this event are not guaranteed to complete.

Is there a workaround that would allow me to minimise my writing operations to storage and hence reduce my CPU usage?

Comment: Use *throttling* (e.g. `debounce`) to write only once a few seconds. Also consider switching to a much faster storage like IndexedDB.

Comment: With IndexedDB you could have some problems in incognito mode (private browsing). Moreover, indexedDB provides bulk read ops, but not bulk write ops (at least for now)

Comment: IndexedDB is usable in incognito windows at least in Chrome. And bulk operations aren't limited to reading: IDBTransaction can be used with multiple `put` requests. Also, even in single update mode IndexedDB would be many times faster than chrome.storage, which is completely unoptimized.

Comment: @wOxxOm IndexedDB sounds good, I'll give it a try!